# Multi-Server Nodes Use Private IP Instead Of Public IP

Tags: amazon-ec2, couchbase

We have our multi-node couchbase server on ec2 instance (one instance each for data / query / index).

When the data node is setup, under server nodes tab in couchbase UI console it shows the private IP address of the node instead of public IP address.

Similarly, when index / query nodes are attached to the data server then it is using the private IP address for each of them to communicate instead of the public IP address.

Now, we want the nodes to be connected using only public IP addresses instead of private IP addresses so that, when we execute our lambda function it would be able to connect to the server.

Please let us know how to proceed further.

Thanks

Comment: Why would intercommunication between nodes have any relation to your Lambda function being able to connect? If you switch to using public IP addresses then all your communication between nodes will basically be going out to the internet and back. This introduces several security issues and greatly increases latency.

Comment: Currently, I am using public IP address in lambda function to connect, it opens the bucket then gives ETDTIMEOUT error like "ETDTIMEOUT when connecting to "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" (private IP address of EC2 Instance)

Comment: This was cross-posted to the Couchbase forums: https://forums.couchbase.com/t/multi-server-nodes-when-joined-use-private-ip-instead-of-public-ip/9484

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have resolved this issue by connecting different nodes using public DNS instead of the elastic IP address which amazon provides i.e: connect your couchbase nodes using public dns like : "ec2-xxx-xxxx".

Hope this will help others who encounter the same issue.